# Gmail emails do not arrive to my GCloud CE

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vesta

I have seen that emails do not arrive to my VM instance in GCloud (CE). I tried Hotmail and they did arrive.

Yes I can send from my server with SparkPostMail to Gmail, but from Gmail to the server back they do not arrive, but according to Gmail it was sent well.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is solved:

I use VestaCP in the GCE, and the problem was that my server did not have read permissions in the SSL:

```
2018-02-08 16:21:02 TLS error on connection from mail-qt0-f180.google.com
 [209.85.216.180] (cert/key setup: cert=/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt
 key=/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.key): Error while reading file. 2018-02-08

16:28:04 Start queue run: pid=25729
```

What I did was put 644 permissions and that was fixed, and I get emails from Gmail.